# CSS Pseudo class active behaves like event bubbling

Tags: css

I am very beginner in css. 
Similar to javascript Event Bubbling when I apply Pseudo code active class it is behaving the same!

I have the HTML as:

```
<div id="newContainer">
<span class="outerPara">I am outer para with <span class="innerPara">InnerPara</span> in me.</span>
</div>
```

And CSS as:

```
#newContainer span.outerPara:active, #newContainer span.innerPara:active{
background-color: red;
}
```

Find the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/sadepu/9M7ek/

When an inner element is active, is the outer element also active or not? If it is in active state, can we stop it or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, CSS pseudo selectors works pretty much the same way event bubbling works in Javascript though you can't do something like  `e.stopPropagation()` in CSS which we can in JS.

If it is really must for you to stop event bubble, I would suggest you to go the Javascript way & `:active` can be emulate by `mousedown ()` & `mouseup()` events.

Answer (score 0):

the outer element is always connected to the inner. i can't say its exactly like event bubbling because that's not my forte, but i know they are similar.

if you want to turn off the outer element, revise your style declarations. you are declaring the background-red on the outer, and inner. target it only on the inner. like so:

```
#newContainer span.outerPara span.innerPara:active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/9M7ek/4/

Comment: //you are declaring the background-red on the outer, and inner. target it only on the inner//
NO!! I want to declare for both but when inner element is clicked only inner element active style should apply. Which is not happening so!!

Comment: i'm really confused...not sure how that's possible. if you could clarify what you mean exactly, it would help.